# DatePicker: Select single date when using range selection

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a **range DatePicker** from Primefaces.
But I also want to be able to just select **one date**.

But if i do so, i won't get any values, just a empty array.
This is because the internal function (which i can't modify) only returns something when two values are given. Or at least I think that.

The workaround which i thought of was just taking the first value of the array by calling it with a javascript function, but i can't access it, because the PF function has neither a function name nor a class.

Here the code of the PrimeFaces function:

```
 if (this.isRangeSelection()) {
                                if (this.value && this.value.length) {
                                    var b = this.value[0],
                                        g = this.value[1];
                                    d = this.formatDateTime(b);
                                    if (g) {
                                        d += " " + this.options.rangeSeparator + " " + this.formatDateTime(g)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Here is my poor javascript attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getArrayValue(){
        console.log("inFunction");
        console.log(window.d.value[0]);
    }
    </script>
```

This is called with this:

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
    <p:datePicker id="range" selectionMode="range"
            value="#{SearchBean.range}" onblur="getArrayValue()">
    </p:datePicker>
 </div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: Why are you trying to get the value from javascript? The idea behind PF is that your processing is done from the server-side, not on the client.

Comment: that was just my first idea, beacuse i don't get any value server sided when I only pick one date. I don't have to necessarily get it from js though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just helped a friend do the same thing that sets the range to both dates being the same you can do it with this JS...

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
function adjustDateRange(widgetVar) {
    var widget = PF(widgetVar);
    var dates = widget.getDate();
    if (dates[0] && !dates[1]) {
        dates[1] = dates[0];
        widget.jq.data().primeDatePicker.updateModel(null, dates);
    }
}
</script>
```

Then in your DatePicker...

```xml
<p:datePicker id="range" 
widgetVar="wgtRange" 
selectionMode="range" 
value="#{SearchBean.range}" 
onblur="adjustDateRange('wgtRange')">
</p:datePicker>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortuatly I get 'widget is undefined' as an error, beacause i don't know what to put in for 'id'. I tried range, wgtrange and suchform:range_input (the id of the input field). Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Sorry Just updated my code it should not have been "id". It should have been widgetVar.